# IE8 style inline-block

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I know there are **A LOT** of questions already made about that issue. Let me elaborate :

## Problem

I have this :

```css
aside {
display: inline-block; 
}

section {
display: inline-block; 
margin-left: 2em;
}
```

Where `aside` is a block on the left and `section` is a block on the right. My whole form containing both blocks is **centered**. It works as intended on **Firefox**, **chrome**, but not on IE8 (*of course...*). IE8 just displays both blocks one over the other (aside over section to be precise).

## Question

How can I make inline-block work in IE8

## What I tried

```css
display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
*zoom: 1;
```

This is a hack for IE7 and below, it doesn't apply to IE8.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

or

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

made no difference at all.

**I don't want to use** `float: left` as it defeats the purpose of having the whole form centered..

Comment: inline-block only works for block elements (p, div, etc) in old IE, and unknown tags are inline elements.

Comment: try using `display:table` and `display:table-cell`

Comment: Are you including the [html5shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv)? You'll need this for legacy IE browsers that don't support the sectioning elements. Add the file so IE knows what these elements are. Then check you styles again...

Comment: @SuperHornet Placing `divs` instead of `aside` and `section` did work. Thanks a lot. Should I delete the question or do you want to type an actual answer below?

Comment: I just post the answer @Sifu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `display:table` and `display:table-cell`